# Trying to connect to MongoDB from a web server using Expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend, web-hosting

I'm trying to set up my website it's already complete and it works locally on my computer but when I transferred it to a hosting site that uses cpanel. The contact page that uses Express as it's backend wasn't working. So I got access to the terminal and set up node js and all of the dependencies I am using through npm but I've run into this error concerning the connection to MongoDB I can't figure out what to do.

```
Photo form listening at http://0.0.0.0:27017
(node:1021120) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
(node:1021120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [cluster0-shard-00-00-wf77h.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ip_address:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:433:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at createConnection (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:577:14)
    at connect (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1021:9)
    at makeConnection (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7)
    at callback (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:247:5)
    at TLSSocket.err (/home/q75z8jpp645w/public_html/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:276:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:1021120) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejectinga promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1021120) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. Inthe future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried various ways to remedy this but to no prevail. I figure it could be I don't have mongodb in my path for the server but I wasn't able to get access to add it so I didn't try could that be it. If anyone has experience with mongodb and hosting websites your help would be greatly appreciated. Also I'm open to using a different database I just opted to use mongo for it's simplicity.

So far i've been studying about how to make websites and webpages but I've never really encountered how to host these sites so when I made my website I wasn't thinking how I could host it with it using nodejs/expressjs, mongodb, and even other modules such as handlebars and lightbox (which seem to be working).

Comment: It could be a firewall visibility issue that you encountering. Your hosting provider may not allow outgoing calls to cluster0-shard-00-00-wf77h.mongodb.net:27017 or mongodb may not accept calls from your hosting provider (less likely). Maybe it's best to use a different hosting provider altogether like heroku.com that make deployments of node.js apps much simpler.

Comment: @StanWiechers thank you I have feeling this could be the reason this is my first time hosting a website besides on Github which is really different. I'm using go daddy.com to host the site do you think it could possibly be the server for MongoDB I don't have it installed on the hosting server. I'll consider Heroku next time but since I already have a really good plan for the year for this hosting I would like to find a way to do it here even if I have to find an alternative approach. I'm only using node.js and MongoDB to save form data. So I could use something else, any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you already turned on 'free access' in mongo atlas, so it sounds like it is a godaddy firewall issue, either the port or the address are not going through the network rules. Reach out to godaddy support.

Comment: Ok I'll try that thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongo atlas service, there is a section called Network access on the left sidebar on your dashboard. You can check free access from anywhere and then the problem will be solved.

Actually mongo atlas put IP address constraints on incoming requests by default.

Comment: I already have that on. It then set another ip address with 0.0.0.0/0. It works when I use the web app locally but for some reason something is not connecting properly when on the hosting server. I can post my backend code if that helps?

Comment: Could it be something else?

Comment: @Myles well the second line MongoNetworkError indication shows your mongo server is limited by IP address or something which is barrier to reach to. Maybe your connection or ISP matters

Comment: Maybe, I think my hosting service is blocking it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems pretty unfortunate turns out its most likely not possible. I'm glad I was able to learn more about how hosting an actual site works but it seems like I'm gonna have to try a different approach for saving data.

Reference: [https://serverfault.com/questions/260924/how-can-i-setup-mongodb-with-godaddy-shared-hosting][1]

Comment: I called my hosting provider and they told me it isn't possible to use mongodb since it's I guess "an intensive database" but I can use SQL through cpanel if I wanted to use mongodb I would have to upgrade to a VPS service.